# Invalid method Fooman_GoogleAnalyticsPlus_Block_Ga::_getOrdersTrackingCode(Array ( ) )

Tags: magento-1.6

I am getting below error after installing Fooman google analytics extension.
I can see method _getOrdersTrackingCode() in core file Ga.php and also in extension file Ga.php

```
Invalid method Fooman_GoogleAnalyticsPlus_Block_Ga::_getOrdersTrackingCode(Array
(
)
)

Trace:
#0 /var/www/project/estella/app/code/community/Fooman/GoogleAnalyticsPlus/Block/Ga.php(232): Varien_Object->__call('_getOrdersTrack...', Array)
#1 /var/www/project/estella/app/code/community/Fooman/GoogleAnalyticsPlus/Block/Ga.php(232): Mage_GoogleAnalytics_Block_Ga->_getOrdersTrackingCode()
#2 /var/www/project/estella/app/code/community/Fooman/GoogleAnalyticsPlus/Block/Ga.php(107): Fooman_GoogleAnalyticsPlus_Block_Ga->_getOrdersTrackingCode('')
#3 /var/www/project/estella/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Fooman_GoogleAnalyticsPlus_Block_Ga->_toHtml()
#4 /var/www/project/estella/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#5 /var/www/project/estella/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#6 /var/www/project/estella/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(582): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#7 /var/www/project/estella/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(522): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('before_head_end', true)
#8 /var/www/project/estella/app/design/frontend/default/shopper/template/page/html/head.phtml(53): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml()
#9 /var/www/project/estella/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/var/www/projec...')
#10 /var/www/project/estella/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/defaul...')
#11 /var/www/project/estella/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#12 /var/www/project/estella/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#13 /var/www/project/estella/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(582): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#14 /var/www/project/estella/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(526): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('head', true)
#15 /var/www/project/estella/app/design/frontend/default/shopper/template/page/1column.phtml(40): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('head')
#16 /var/www/project/estella/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/var/www/projec...')
#17 /var/www/project/estella/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/defaul...')
#18 /var/www/project/estella/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#19 /var/www/project/estella/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#20 /var/www/project/estella/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(529): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#21 /var/www/project/estella/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(391): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#22 /var/www/project/estella/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(132): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#23 /var/www/project/estella/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(52): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->_renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'shopper_home')
#24 /var/www/project/estella/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/controllers/IndexController.php(45): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'shopper_home')
#25 /var/www/project/estella/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(420): Mage_Cms_IndexController->indexAction()
#26 /var/www/project/estella/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#27 /var/www/project/estella/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#28 /var/www/project/estella/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(349): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#29 /var/www/project/estella/app/Mage.php(640): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#30 /var/www/project/estella/index.php(80): Mage::run('', 'store')
#31 {main}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: please go to https://github.com/fooman/googleanalyticsplus then try latest version and after this fill a bugreport if it still happens

Comment: see comment before, because of 3th party module

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error appears not because `Fooman_GoogleAnalyticsPlus_Block_Ga` have no method `_getOrdersTrackingCode`.

That is because `Fooman_GoogleAnalyticsPlus_Block_Ga` extends `Mage_GoogleAnalytics_Block_Ga`. And the error appears on

```
parent::_getOrdersTrackingCode();
```

It means that `Mage_GoogleAnalytics_Block_Ga` has no method `_getOrdersTrackingCode`.

Check that.

Comment: _getOrdersTrackingCode() is present in Mage_GoogleAnalytics_Block_Ga class

Comment: Thanks Olekssi. The problem was that somebody has copied Mage_GoogleAnalytics_Block_Ga in local directory and _getOrdersTrackingCode() method is not in this local directory file.